# How do I find depth and height of all nodes in a bounded semilattice?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, lattices

I'm writing a program where I have a bounded semilattice (it has a root element at the top, all edges point downwards, and a node may have multiple parents). I need to precompute each node's depth (the max number of edges from the root node) and height (the max number of edges to any leaf). I have a naive implementation for just the heights where every node is compared to all it's descendants, so probably O(n^2). What is a faster algorithm that computes both height and depth?

Comment: How is the semilattice represented?  As a graph in adjacency list format?  Are there any basic operations that are available (e.g., join/meet)?  Have you tried applying topological sorting and then visiting nodes in topologically sorted order?

Comment: It's represented as vertices with pointers to other vertices, only in the downwards direction. The only operation is to traverse an edge. I didn't think of topological sorting so I'll look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do a topological sort and then traverse the nodes in reverse topologically sorted order, you can annotate each node with its height in linear time.  Similarly, you can annotate each node with its depth in linear time by traversing in topologically sorted order.  This achieves linear running  time, which is significantly faster than the quadratic time approach you mention.

Comment: As I'm iterating over each node, how do I know what value to assign it?

Comment: @Brent,  For height, its height is 1 + the max of the heights of its successors (children).  For depth, you look at the predecessors.

Comment: Wouldn't that put it back in O(n^2)?

Comment: @Brent, no, it would not.

Comment: Awesome. Would you offer a guess as to what the asymptotic performance is?

Comment: @Brent, see the last sentence of my answer.  Linear running time means $O(|V|+|E|)$.

Comment: That can't possibly be right. Iterating over all the nodes is linear, but also inspecting adjacent nodes upon each of them means it's got to be greater than linear time.

Comment: @Brent, nope.  Try applying that same reasoning to topological sort (which also "inspects adjacent nodes upon each of them"), then read through the running time analysis of topological sort to understand why it is still $O(|V|+|E|)$.  The total time to inspect all adjacent nodes of a vertex is equal to at most the number of edges out of it; totalling this over all nodes gives you a total of $|E|$.  (Not $|V|^2$ as you might naively think.)

Comment: I see. Thanks so much for bearing with me. I may need to re-examine the algorithm I have too, as my O(n^2) assessment may have been incorrect. Thanks again.